If the 1-carbon in an organic compound is the compound nearest a substituent group, why is this compound not 1,2-dichlorobut-3-yne?

It names it as if the carbon furthest from the chlorine substituent on the end is the 1-carbon.
Why is the name: 3,4-dichlorobutyne and not 1,2-dichlorobut-3-yne

Possibly because doublehand triple bonds may have higher priority than substituents and thus get the lowest numbers. But I'll leave a full answer to those better experienced with IUPAC nomenclature.

The name 3,4-dichlorobutyne cannot be a IUPAC conforming name as it is missing a locant. So this at least needs to be 3,4-dichlorobut-1-yne. Whether or not this is the PIN I'm not able to answer. But you might find it yourself: https://iupac.qmul.ac.uk/BlueBook/

I think 3,4-dichlorobut-1-yne would be the PIN (Preferred IUPAC Name), because according to IUPAC Blue Book P-14.4, in the (e) section it is mentioned that: low locants are given first to multiple bonds as a set and then to double bonds.
Hence, multiple bonds would be given more priority while naming. So, in your case, the triple bond would be assigned lower number than Chlorine substituents.
Hence, 3,4-dichlorobut-1-yne would be PIN.
Hope this helps.
